# Moving UIButton with touch

Tags: ios, events, uiview, uibutton, touch

I'm using :

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(moved:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

Function code move:

```
- (IBAction)moved:(id)sender {
UIButton *t = sender;

UITouch *touch = [touch self];

CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView: self];

t.center = touchPoint;
}
```

So, when I start to drag the button, it suddenly appears in left up corner (Coord: 0;0). I thought this was a problem because `CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView: self];` works in wrong way. 
I've got 3 classes: viewController, which makes implement of:

```
view = [[MainView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view frame] ];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

where view is object of class mainview(subclass uiview).    In mainview i make object of class Button(subclass uiview):

```
[self addSubview:but];
```

Then in class Button i make UIButton, associating with event UIControlEventTouchDragInside(see beginning of post).

So how should i correct my code, that button move to touch point correctly???

P.S. Sorry for my awful English=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to stick with UIControlEventTouchDragInside then use the snippet below. Personally I would use [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

```
- (IBAction)moved:(UIButton *)sender {
    UITouch *touch = [touch self];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView: sender.superview];
    sender.center = touchPoint;
}
```

Comment: Bartosz Ciechanowski - thanks for good idea! But it looks like the same problem; for example my touch point (x;y), but it recognized as (x-100;y-100)!?? In my previous projects all was fine, but now, I have not idea what happened.

Comment: I'd go straight to UIPanGestureRecognizer then :)